# AngularJS Charts not updating data correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm using angular charts, and I'm trying to display a chart that updates depending the current item selected, It works well on the first item I select, but after I select a second Item, It seems like the data from the first item selected is still present on the chart (although the data has changed completely), the problem looks like this:

[image: dataproblem]

```
app.controller("itemsAppController", function ($scope, $timeout, itemsData, itemsFactory, $filter) {
$scope.items = itemsData.Items;


$scope.itemSelected = false;
$scope.currentItem = {};

$scope.selectItem = function (itemId) {
    $scope.itemSelected = false;

    var foundItem = $filter('filter')($scope.items, { ItemId: itemId }, true);
    var item = foundItem[0];
    $scope.currentItem = item;  

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.itemSelected = true;
    }, 500);
};

$scope.chartOptions = {
    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>%"
}
});
```

The canvas:

```
<div ng-show="itemSelected">
    <canvas class="chart chart-pie" data="currentItem.MostUsedChampionsPrePatchData" labels="currentItem.MostUsedChampionsPrePatchLabels" legend="true" options="chartOptions"></canvas>
</div>
```

And the object data looks like this:

[image: objectdata]

Any ideas of what is causing this problem?

**EDIT:** Here's a fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/PGjtS/130/

When recreating it, the problem arise when I included the animation and the ng-show

Comment: I must add that this happens with other types of charts too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423899/why-does-chart-update-fail-when-its-container-has-ng-show-on-it)

The problem seems to be caused because of DOM manipulation

Using `ng-if` or `ng-switch` instead of `ng-show` solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation you can try this...
If you want to reload the canvas send a broadcast using:

`$scope.$broadcast("$reload", {});`

This wil repaint the charts (for example when a chart became visible)

Answer (score 1):

I've got this issue a couple of time.

Just put your update chart code in a new function like "updateChart" and call it using something like this :

```
$timeout(updateChart(data), 200)
```

It will solve your issue.

Edit:

Move your :

```
$scope.currentItem = item;
```

in your timeout and it's gonna be working :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems (from your picture) like your selectItem is triggering repeatedly - you might want double check the trigger for that.

You might also want to check the `tooltipTemplate` - though you append %, it doesn't look (from your picture) that your numbers add up to 100.

Comment: You might also want to post a fiddle and replicate the problem - the code available in the question is not much to go on (it doesn't show the trigger, the injected services...)

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the problem, that's why i didn't post a fiddle. About the injected services, 'itemsData' is just a json object that came from a server, and the trigger looks like this `ng-click="selectItem(item.ItemId)"`, I checked it up on the debugger, and It's not getting triggered more than once. I'll keep trying to replicate it on fiddle though, thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/PGjtS/130/ I posted the wrong fiddle before, lol. Here's the correct fiddle